# Backbone.js model sync--where set method?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have written a custom Backbone.sync method that looks as follows:

```
sync: function(method, model, options) {
switch(method)
case 'create':
//do stuff here
}
```

Later on, I set everything up using the set() and call the sync by calling save(). Although I can set the backbone model's attributes, where can I set the method to 'create', 'delete'. etc?

Comment: You do it in the view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify the `method` argument to `Backbone.sync` yourself. The different methods are used in the following scenarios:

- `create` - when you call `model.save()`  on a new model (which does not have id)
- `update` - when you call `model.save()` on an existing model (which has an id)
- `patch` - when you call `model.save(..., {patch:true})`
- `delete` - when you call `model.destroy()`
- `read` - when you call `model.fetch()` or `collection.fetch()`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you're doing here based off the code, but I am assuming you are calling an AJAX-like method with create and delete. If I am understanding you correctly, these methods should go in your views.